# Cannot revoke app permission for YouTube channel account

Tags: youtube, google-oauth

I am creating an application that asks for permission to manage a YouTube account (Google account) via OAuth2.

This works great, however the problem I'm facing is if the user decides to use a YouTube channel account that is linked to their Google account to grant permissions to our application, I can't find out how to allow them to revoke their permission.

For instance, if our app is authed to a normal Google account, we can go to this page: https://security.google.com/settings/u/0/security/permissions and then revoke the permission by finding our application in the list and clicking the "revoke access" button on the right.

We cannot do this for the linked YouTube channel account.  There doesn't seem to be any such permissions dashboard available for these accounts.

When using the aforementioned dashboard, usually you can "switch accounts" by clicking on your account picture in the upper right side of the page.  However, when I do this, the linked account is not listed.

Comment: Any solution? I'm having same problem right now.

Comment: @Giedrius haven't found one yet :(

Answer (score 5):

You can revoke access at this page:
https://accounts.google.com/delegateaccountselector?continue=https://accounts.google.com/issuedauthsubtokens

Answer (score 2):

It looks like when you first select which channel/sub-account to see apps for, it doesn't actually select that channel properly.

Once on the list of connected apps (for the wrong channel), I had to click my icon in the top-right and select the correct channel, and then the youtube apps showed up!

Answer (score 0):

For me it shows up on that page as:

Project Default Service Account
Has access to YouTube